# with get youtube video title in php

Tags: php, javascript, youtube-api

I am saving youtube video id's in my database and want to show that video's title in my application. I got the following code and working well. But if we add a video with "#" in its title then it will return "No title" even if its title is valid ...

Please give me a hand ...

Try this video id :  4O7kTOTg1UE  ( its having a "#" in its URL , this is not working )

My code looks like

```
    if($content=@file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$video_id)) {
        parse_str($content, $ytarr);
if(isset($ytarr['title'])) {
        $myvideos[$i]['video_title']=$ytarr['title'];

                $i++;
}

else {
$myvideos[$i]['video_title']="No title";
$i++;
}


    }
    else {
        $myvideos[$i]['video_title']="No title";
$i++;
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence of # in the URL, is causing it to misbehave. It treats, this is a different named anchor on the web page. Please clarify, where are you adding # with title, in DB or the page?

Comment: I am getting the # from the youtube video's title  Please check http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4O7kTOTg1UE